# understanding validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

My understanding of validates_associated, as per the rails guide, is that it should ensure that an associated record is valid before saving.  For example:

```
class ForumPost < AR:Base
  has_many :replies
end

class ForumPostReply < AR:Base
  validates_length_of :content, :minimum => 20
end
```

Unit Test:

```
forum_post = Factory.create(:forum_post)
forum_post.replies.build(:content => 'some content')   #content too short, not valid
forum_post.save
forum_post.errors.should be_empty  #empty because reply was not expected to be validated
```

Should I expect this save to fail given the fact that I didn't specify validates_associated :replies in my ForumPost model?  It seems to save just fine which is not what I expected as I had not specified validates associated.

So if the models behave this way without validates_associated specified, then what does validates_associated do?

Comment: Sounds like you're contradicting yourself. You don't specify `validates_associated :replies` and it saves fine even though it's an invalid child entity. What's the problem?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time I contradicted myself. If it checks validation when saving with out validates_associated, what does validates_associated do?

Answer (score 2):

Figured I would move this to an answer. You say,

"Should I expect this save to fail given the fact that I didn't specify `validates_associated :replies` in my ForumPost model?"

No, you should expect it to save because you **don't** specify `validates_associated :replies`

"It seems to save just fine which is not what I expected as I had not specified validates associated."

It seems to save just fine because it **isn't** validating the associated because you didn't specify it.